# Black Screen Problem - Installing 18.04 from USB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, usb, msi

I have Windows 10 installed on my system, and need to install Ubuntu 18.04 as the second OS. (dual boot)

I created a bootable usb, and trying to install Ubuntu from it. However when I select the install or try Ubuntu options, I get a black screen only.

I tried nomodeset setting but nothing changes. (both with and without quiet splash option)

What do you suggest me to try?

I am using a MSI GE63 8RF notebook with NVIDIA GTX1070, Intel I7-8750H.

edit: I added checksum results for the ISO file.

[image: checksum]

Comment: I suspect that there is a problem with the built-in linux driver for the NVIDIA GTX1070 graphics card. Please try with the [boot option](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. It should give you some basic but working graphics. Later on, in the installed system, you should also use `nomodeset` and then maybe try to install an nvidia proprietary driver to get the full power of the graphics card.

Comment: @sudodus as I mentioned in my post, I tried nomodeset. do you have any other boot option suggestions that might help?

Comment: Sorry, I was reading your question too quickly. I will try to find some other tip (or link) for you.

Comment: 1. Try with the brand new (and improved) first point release, the iso file [ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso); 2. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921674/ubuntu-16-04-laptop-gtx-1070-cannot-install-from-usb), that might add some tips, You can also search AskUbuntu or the internet with the search phrase (without quotes) 'nvidia 1070 graphics boot option' or something similar (that's how I found the link supplied). Good luck :-)

Comment: @karel I have already seen that link before opening this topic. That did not help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a similar laptop (MSI GE73 8RF).

**Quick Solution**: 
In this particular case, system should be able to boot with kernel parameter `acpi=off`.

**Proper Solution**: 
If the quick solution works, update the BIOS: 
[Bios update for MSI GE63 8RF](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GE63-Raider-RGB-8RF.html#down-bios) 
The zip file contains a guide (pdf) on how to update the BIOS.

---

For me, after BIOS update, mouse and keyboard did not work on live booted Ubuntu 
Solution is to use kernel parameter `iommu=soft`.

Once Ubuntu is installed, the kernel parameter is not required.

Answer (score -1):

My best guess based on the information you have provided us is that you either downloaded the wrong version of Ubuntu (like an ARM version instead of AM64), or there was something wrong with your flashing process. What program did you use to flash the USB stick?

Comment: I used Rufus, and I think I have the correct version: ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.ISO

Comment: I would try to use [Etcher](https://etcher.io/), just to rule out that variable. If it causes the same problem, I would try to re-download your ISO from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso Let me know if that helps!!!