# Unable to install Ubuntu on Dell with dual graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, dell

I'm trying to upgrade an old Dell Inspiron 660s with a Zotac GT1030 graphics card. It comes with a built-in Intel graphics chip, but I would want to use the GT1030 solely.

However, when I try to install Ubuntu 18.04, the installer almost immediately fails with the error "DRM: nouveau failed to create kernel channel -22".

That sounds similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921674/ubuntu-16-04-laptop-gtx-1070-cannot-install-from-usb). That poster mentioned that the problem was a bug in Ubuntu triggered by the dual graphics cards, and they were able to fix the problem by disabling the onboard graphics chip in their bios. However, checking the 660s bios shows no options to disable onboard graphics.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Documenting my steps, in case this is helpful to anyone else.

I [followed this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-the-nomodeset-quiet-and-splash-kernel-parameters-mean/716966) I added the "nomodeset" option to my kernel boot parameters, and that allowed the installer to complete.

However, now when it boots, it hangs at the step "Started Gnome Display Manager", and even after 15 minutes, nothing else happens. I have a small monitor connected to the built-in HDMI port, and a tv connected to the GT1030's HDMI port. When I boot, I briefly see the Ubuntu logo on the tv, but then it reverts to a black screen, so it must be partially working. Yet Gnome never seems to start on the monitor display. I can login via Alt+Fn and install packages, so aside from the X Server, everything else seems to be working fine.

To fix this, I followed [these instructions](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/07/25/nvidia-384-59-released-gt-1030-mx150-support/) to install the proprietary graphics driver PPA, and then the appropriate Nvidia driver from the command line. After rebooting, now both HDMI outputs are showing the full Ubuntu desktop. If I disconnect the monitor, the tv HDMI works fine standalone.